# Java - logical thinking behind this array exercise

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

I need some help with the logic behind the below array exercise.

Given an unordered array of strings with n length, I need to create a new array that will only contain values that occur more than once in the given array. The new array needs to maintain the order of the values.

- Example #1

Input  {"cat","dog", "dog", "mouse", "car", "house, "mouse","cat","dog"}

Output {"cat","dog", "dog", "mouse", "mouse","cat","dog"}

Some constraints:

- Only allowed for, enhanced for, and while loops.

From what I understand, first I have to find the length of the new array which is determined by the length of the original array minus the non-duplicate values. Can this be done with a single for loop?

Then once I have the new array created, I need to loop through the original array and append any of the duplicate values to it.

Below is what I managed to put together so far but I feel like I am no closer to the final result than I was days ago.

I am more after the logical thinking behind the problem but any help with the code is also greatly appreciated.

```
public class ArrayTesting
{
    public static String[] duplicatedOnly(String []arr)
    {
        int nonDupes = 0; // count how many elements are NOT duplicated
        String current = arr[0]; 
        int len = arr.length;
        
        //Check first vs last
        if (arr[0].equals(arr[len-1])){
            nonDupes++;
        }
        //Determine how many non duplicates to establish length of newArray
        for (int i = 1; i < len; i++){
            if(!current.equals(arr[i])){
                nonDupes++;
            }
        }

        //Declare newArray + position
        String[] newArray = new String[nonDupes];
        int pos = 0;
        //Iterate through existing array and append any elements which are duplicated
        for (int i = 0; i < len-1; i++){
            for (int j = i+1; j < len; j++){
                if (arr[i].equals(arr[j])){
                    newArray[pos] = arr[j];
                    pos++;                                            
                }
            }
        }
        //Check first vs last
        if (arr[0].equals(arr[len-1])){
            newArray[pos] = arr[0];
        }
        
        //Return newArray
        return newArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your approach of detecting non-duplicates will throw you off.  For example, in the set `{a,a,b}`, it would find two non-duplicates where an 'a' and 'b' are compared.

Comment: To get a count of non-duplicates, you could, either in a loop or a function, answer the question: "how many instances of this word are in this array?"  If the answer is 1, you know the word is a non-duplicate.

Comment: If I run it with {a,a,b} the nonDupes value is 1 which is correct but I do know that the code doesn't function properly because if I run it with {a,b,b,c,c,} for example, it will return 4 as the nonDupes value. Any suggestions on a better approach? 
My understanding is that I need to try every element against all other elements to determine if it's considered a duplicate. If not, then theoretically that should append nonDupes.

Comment: I think your concept of counting non-duplicates to determine the proper length of your unfilled array is a good one.  Don't try to compare first and last separately.  You can have a for loop that evaluates each word, and inside that a for loop that counts occurrences of that word in the entire list.  That gets you the size of the array.  Populating that array will be very similar, as you can add any word whose count > 1.